# MasterPass Merchant Server SDK - Request Token Junit

Tags: java, junit, sdk, mockito, mastercard

I have Implemented Masterpass SDK in one of my Project for Checkout purpose.
The API is used to get request Token by passing the CallBackUrl and OrginURL
The API is implemented successfully and its working as expected.

Issue: I am facing issue with creating junit test cases using Mockito.

Code:

```
public void invokeService(AuthTokenRequestBean requestBean) throws Exception {
        retrieveAuthTokenService = new RetrieveAuthTokenService(requestBean);
        when(processorFactory.createService(eq(RetrieveAuthTokenService.class),
                                              any(AuthTokenRequestBean.class))).
            thenReturn(retrieveAuthTokenService);
        Mockito.when(retrieveAuthTokenService.getOutput()).thenReturn(response);
        Mockito.when(retrieveAuthTokenService.process(any(FlowCtx.class))).thenReturn(response);
    }
```

Exception:

rg.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:

when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Need help if anyone work on those apis for mocking using junit.
Is There any other Framework that can be used for mocking.

Answer (score 0):

We Can Mock the MasterPass SDK implementation using PowerMockito. Since This contains Static methods and can be mocked with PowerMockito.

Code Snippet is below ..

@Mock
    private ProcessorFactory processorXXXX;

public void setupAndXXXProcessor(AuthTokenRequestXXXX requestBean) throws Exception {
        retrieveAuthTokenProcessor = new RetrieveAuthXXXXXX(requestBean);
        PowerMockito.when(
                processorXXXX.createProcessor(eq(RetrieveAuthXXXXXX.class), any(AuthTokenRequestXXXX.class)))
                .thenReturn(retrieveAuthTokenProcessor);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(RequestTokenApi.class);
        PowerMockito.when(RequestTokenApi.create(anyString())).thenReturn("createRequestTokenResponse");
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ShoppingCartApi.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ShoppingCartApi.create(any(ShoppingCartRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn(createShoppingCartResponse());
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MerchantInitializationApi.class);
        PowerMockito.when(MerchantInitializationApi.create(any(MerchantInitializationRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn("createMerchantInitializationResponse");

}